# Index does not print

Tags: indexing

I'm currently trying to add an index to my `.tex` file but it never appears in my pdf document.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{color}


\newtheorem{stell}{Stelling}[section]
\newtheorem{gev}{Gevolg}[section]
\newtheorem{lemm}{Lemma}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definitie}[section]
\newtheorem{vb}{Voorbeeld}[section]

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}


\title{Book}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}\index{first section}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

**Edit** I had forgotten to add the `\printindex' in my message. But it was allready in my tex-file.

Comment: where do you print the index? There is no `\printindex` command

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Expanding on daleif's comment: LaTeX can't know *where* you want your index, so a `\printindex` command is necessary in the location. Don't forget to run MakeIndex.

Comment: egreg: how can I run my MakeIndex, I don't see such a file in my directory?

Comment: it is called `makeindex` and it is a part of your LaTeX instalaltion. In most cases you will have a `makeidnex` button in your editor somewhere. Otherwise you need to run `makeindex file.idx` manually. This creates the index ready for LaTeX to include